# Ошибка ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to LPSTR

Tags: c++, строки, winapi, const, строковый-литерал

Хочу создать строку с типом `LPSTR`, чтобы менять ее во время работы программы, а потом преобразовать в `LPCSTR` (это для передачи последнего аргумента в функцию `CreateFont`).

Создаю вот так строку:

```cpp
LPSTR currFontd = "Arial";
```

Выходит такая ошибка во время компиляции:

```
17:25:22,75 [C] #>g++ -mwindows window.cpp -o out.exe                                                                 
window.cpp:20:19: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'LPSTR' {aka 'char*'} [-Wwrite-strings]         
20 | LPSTR currFontd = "Arial";
```

Что не так делаю? Может можно использовать другую строку, чтобы потом можно было передать в эту функцию?

Comment: Создавайте именно `LPCSTR` — константную строку. Ну нельзя менять в программе литералы :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы по сути делаете

```
char * currFontd = "Arial";
```

Получается, что вы намерены (может, и нет, но требуете у компилятора такого права) *изменить строковый литерал*, например,

```
currFontd[0] = 'Q';
```

Литерал же — строка неизменяемая, и вы не можете обращаться с ней иначе как с константной,  через `const char *` или, что то же `LPCSTR`.

Работайте или сразу с `LPCSTR`, или с копией литерала —

```
char currFontd[] = "Arial";
```

или там

```
string currFontd = "Arial";
```

Comment: Спасибо, `LPCSTR` действительно работает! Думал с этим типом нельзя изменять переменную и этот тип не подойдет... Оказывается константа это не про const указатель.

Comment: [An LPCSTR is a 32-bit pointer to a constant null-terminated string of 8-bit Windows (ANSI) characters.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/f8d4fe46-6be8-44c9-8823-615a21d17a61) Я нигде не писал о константном указателе, только о константной строке, т.е. указателе на константные символы, `const char *`, а не `char * const`.